# Launch app with absolute path does not woks

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm quite new in Linux environments, but for this one, I need help on bash. I'm on Kubuntu 14.04 x64

I have an embedded JRE for my business application , placed like this:

```
app_root/run.sh (my script)
app_root/jre/bin/java (executable from Oracle JRE)
app_root/app/someJars.jar
```

In my script I launch the Java app like this: `/home/foo/app_root/jre/bin/java (some_options) -jar (my_main_jar)`  etc ...

but it raise a `'no file or directory found' (code 127)`  !!!
On other computers, this script launch correctly the JRE

Another test I made, in Konsole, if type `/home/foo/app_root/jre/bin/java`, I've got the error.

But I change dir : `cd /home/foo/app_root/jre/bin` 
and I type : `java`. it works !

what's the matter with this ?

Comment: Please can you show me the complete command, with options that you are executing.

Comment: the complete command line is not the problem because it works on other linux machine. the uncomprehensive thing is why a program can't be launch by calling its full path !!!

Comment: Yeah, but it would help me to see the command. It won't hurt to show me, and if not unfortunataly I cannot help any more.

Comment: I don't think it will help you : 
/home/foo/app_root/jre/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxNewSize=32M -XX:NewSize=32M -Xms768m -Dapp.log.file=$APP_LOG_FILE -jar app-ui-swing-1.2.1.jar --option app.launch.mode full --option app.basedir /home/foo/app_root